# Issue Identifying resource URI - Restful web services

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0, restful-architecture

I am working on an application that uses rest webservices where a uri has been invoked from a .js file.

```
var invokeWS = "/resource/domain/program/tasks";
jQuery.getJSON(invokeWS ,data)
```

While looking at all the jar's I found out that the class corresponding to program is present in a package "com.company.project.webapps.util.rest.service" as below

```
package com.company.project.webapps.util.rest.service;

@Path("/program")      
 public class Program extends RS
  {

     @Path("/tasks")
     @GET
      public get...()
      {
      }
  }
```

I do not see any mapping url in web.xml but the the webservice call made through .js would some how pick the correct path and invokes the service.

Can you please let me know if this can be achieved in a any other way as I do not see any entries in web.xml of the applicaiton.

Thanks
Awanish

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Are you asking how it works without web.xml or how it can be achieved without web.xml? Can you please rephrase your question to where it is a bit more clear

Comment: The first one - how it works without web.xml. How does a js all like the one above know to exactly to look for the class file without a mapping being done in web.xml. I am not aware if this can be achieved without an entry in web.xml mentioning the package which need to be referred to.

Comment: Look for a class that extends `Application` or `ResourceConfig` that is annotated with `@ApplicationPath`. This  is the way to configure Jersey without web.xml. You can read more [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet.3)